# Is the Search API module able to do range facets on numeric values?

Tags: commerce, search

I'm using Drupal Commerce, Search API, and [Facets API](http://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi); I'd like to put the product prices as a facet. Configuring my search API index, I managed to get this facet, but the Search API module doesn't seem capable of handling price ranges facets. This is how the facet looks like.

- 1230,23
- 340,21
- ...

I'd like it to be like the following.

- From 10 to 100
- From 100 to 200
- ...

It seems that there is existing code for handling ranges, but not decimal ranges.

Did I miss something?

Comment: I tried the search_api_ranges module, and it doesn't fit here for two reasons: 1) It only brings a slider (don't need it) and 2) it fails and throws *a lot* of PHP notices

Answer (score 3):

[commerce_search_api](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api) sounds like exactly like what you're looking for.  Be aware of the commerce >= 1.4 dependency as of this writing.

The module includes a product display index (configurable at admin/config/search/search_api/index/product_display):

> - Auto-generated search index that includes all product display node    types* and related product data.
> - Auto-generated facets for all node type categories and product attributes.

I've used the price facet filters, with and without the search_api_ranges widget, with great success.

Answer (score 2):

This was asked long time ago, but as I have just landed here, let me add another answer - it seems that [Facet API Ranges](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_ranges) is the module you are looking for:

What it could give you:

[image: how it looks]

Configuration options:

[image: configuration options]

Comment: I ended up writing my own facet block rendering function, but I guess this would be solution. Please note that at the time, all of Search API, Facet API were terribly bugguy, and Facet API Ranges existed only in -dev version.

Comment: Hi Pierre can you please share the source code what you have written.